# SSIS Data Flow with custom encryption dll in script component VERY SLOW

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, ssis

I am do a data conversion where sensitive data in the old database was not encrypted.  We are building a new database and front end application and as I'm transforming the data, there are 2 columns I need to encrypt as they are loaded into the new database.  I'm using a simple select query from a staging table (OLE DB SQL Database connection) of the 3 columns I need (a unique ID and the 2 columns that need to be encrypted), then I have a script component containing the C# code referencing a custom dll that's in the GAC, then it processes the rows, and then it's loading into another staging table (OLE DB SQL Database) with the ID, and the 2 columns with the encrypted values.  I have 2.3M rows to process and I'm using the fast-load option with TABLE LOCK and CHECK CONSTRAINTS (there really aren't any) for the destination staging table.  However, this process is taking anywhere between 14 and 24 HOURS to complete!  The variance in loading times was from 2 different environments, one was my PC--which ran faster, and the other from a virtual server that was loaded up with much more memory--which ran MUCH slower oddly enough. At any rate, neither one of these times are good at all, and I just wanted to see if there's anything I can do to significantly speed this up?

Here is the C# script within the Script Component:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
  public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   {
       Row.ClaimNumberEncr = DAV.CMS.Core.Common.Crypto.EncryptFromStringAES (Row.ClaimNumber, "abc123defg").Entity; 
       Row.SSNEncr = DAV.CMS.Core.Common.Crypto.EncryptFromStringAES (Row.AlternateClaimantID, "abc123defg").Entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote some custom cryptography code and your package is taking a really long time. It *sounds* like the cryptography code is likely the culprit. The additional RAM on the server, while generally a good thing, is like ineffective as cryptography is traditionally a CPU, or GPU, intensive activity. You'd likely need them to dial up the number of CPUs exposed to the VM to see if it has an impact.

Comment: Step 1. Establish a baseline. Remove the Script task or set the _IsNull property to true on these two columns and run the package (outside of the debugger within Visual Studio). That is your theoretical maximum throughput. If it's 11 hours, your problem lies elsewhere. Step 2, repeat the run but this time with a `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT *` so you have a reasonable set of data to work with. Record that time. Step 3, enable the encryption for one of the columns. Record that time. Step 4, enable both column's encryption, how does that time increase compare - linear, double, something else?

Comment: Finally, look at the data types for what you have in your data flow. if you are using LOB values (text/image/n/varchar(max)/varbinary(max)) - either in the source or have defined the encrypted output columns as being of those, then it can have an appreciable drag on data processing in SSIS.

Comment: billinkc, you bring up very good points, I am pretty sure it's the encryption process taking a long time.  My destinations are int, varbinary(50) and varbinary(50), so not too huge.  I have loaded these same records with various other column types, and more columns from one table to another in various other packages, and depending on how many columns and how many transforms are being done in between, it only takes anywhere from a few seconds to 2 hours at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at both environments, and BINGO, my laptop actually has 4 CPU's while the virtual server only has 2.  While my laptop has only 8GB of ram and the VS has 18GB, obviously the difference is in the # of CPU's.  I'm going to have them double my CPUs on the VS and see if that helps.  Thank you for your suggestions, I guess we'll just have to live with the processing time being what it is based on the encryption taking up the time, but try to beef up my VS and get it down to the fastest possible.

Comment: SQL Server has inbuilt encryption capabilities - have you considered that?

Comment: I have but our development team insists on using their own custom encryption.